# Device manager vs wmi core count

Tags: windows-server-2008

A VM Windows 2008 R2 server was just setup with 12 cores and 12 GB ram.  When I look at Task Manager only 8 cores show.  When I look at WMI only 8 cores show.  Looking in Device Manger 12 processors show.  Can someone explain the difference between the core count in Device manager vs. WMI?

We have three machines with this config and they all show this way.  In addition Computer Properties only says 4 processors; which matches with the 8 cores reported in WMI (4 * 2).

Oh and there are 12 cores allocated to this VM in the VMWare configuration

Is it that the Windows 2008 R2 license/version only allows up to 4 CPU?  Is there a way I can check?

Comment: Sorry, don't know version of ESXi, though I assume tools are up to date and OS patches as it's a new install.  Bad to assume I know, I will need to check with the group who stood up the machine. Tools => 9.05, Build-1065307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system is Windows 2008 R2 Standard which only supports 4 processors.

So even though there are 6 processors installed, 12 cores, only 4 processors, 8 cores are usable.

I will ask our vitalization team if there is a processor they can emulate which contains 4 cores per processor.  Not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score -2):

This is most likely due to the difference between Physical and Virtual cores.

What type of processor are you using? I'd bet dogs-to-dollars that you may be using Intel processors with Hyper-threading. If I recall, most Intel physical processors have two 'cores' each. (I.e. Ivy Bridge is a 4-processor platform with a total of 8 cores, two per physical processor.)

Comment: 12 / 2 != 8. Something else is likely going on here.